# c# how to create lots of similar variables

Tags: c#, wpf

In my project I need to create lots (around 100) of very similiar variables. Is there a template style or something I can use?

```
private double _num;
public double Num
{
    get { return _num; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _num)
        {
            _num = value;
            DisplayNum = _num;
        }
    }
}

private Brush _numColor = Brushes.Black;
public Brush NumColor
{
    get { return _numColor; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _numColor)
        {
            _numColor = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("NumColor");
         }
     }
}

private double _displayNum;
public double DisplayNum
{
    get { return _displayNum; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _displayNum)
        {
            _displayNum = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("DisplayNum");
        }
    }
}
```

I know I could use an array, etc, but that's not what I want.

I want to do something like
"Create new string stat" and it would create the above but with "stat" instead of "num" and "string" instead of "double" at compile time.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're looking for code snippets.  However, you probably shouldn't be doing that.  You may want `ICustomTypeDescriptor`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into those. Wasn't sure on the proper terminology for what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code snippets are indeed the way to go, here's the one I wrote for INPC properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>propc</Title>
            <Shortcut>propc</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for property and backing field with change notification</Description>
            <Author>Mark Feldman</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>type</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property type</ToolTip>
                    <Default>int</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>property</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property name</ToolTip>
                    <Default>MyProperty</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[private $type$ _$property$;
        public $type$ $property$
        {
            get { return this._$property$;}
            set { this._$property$ = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
        $end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

I bind this to "propc", so all I have to is type that in DevStudio, press Tab and then fill out each field as required.

Comment: Thank you.  I looked into snippets and figured them out. Very nice and solved my problem.